# How can I skip building an NDK module for one ABI?

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile, gnu-make

I have an NDK project which does some funky stuff that causes one of my modules to fail the build for the `arm64-v8a` ABI. This is OK with me, but I'd like to skip building the module for that ABI.

Currently, I just keep the entire module inside a conditional, like so:

`ifneq ($(BUILD_ODD_MODULE),false)
  # Module definition ....
endif`

Then, when I want it built I enable the block and either change the `APP_ABI` in `Application.mk` to exclude `arm64-v8a`, or tolerate the errors. How can I just get that block to build for all ABIs the app is building for, but skip `arm64-v8a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like:

```
if (not building for arm64-v8a)  <-- the unknown part
   LOCAL_MODULE := foo
   ...
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
endif
```

The first line in the above block could be expressed as:

```
ifneq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!